# Grunt-wiredep done without errors but doesn't inject dependencies

Tags: php, gruntjs, wiredep

I'm trying to connect wiredep with my project, with no success. I have the bower_components and bower.json inside assets/, and the gruntfile.js in the root directory. Here's the relevant gruntfile:

```
wiredep: {
    target: {
        src: [
            'grunt-test.html',
            'application/views/inc/inc_scripts.php',
            'application/views/inc/inc_head.php'
        ],
        directory: 'assets/bower_components',
        bowerJson: 'assets/bower.json',
        fileTypes: {
            php: {
                block: /(([\s\t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
                detect: {
                    js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
                    css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
                },
                replace: {
                    js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>', // <-- Change this line
                    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
                }
            },
            html: {
                block: /(([\s\t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
                detect: {
                    js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
                    css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
                },
                replace: {
                    js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>', // <-- Change this line
                    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I run `grunt wiredep --verbose` and get the following output:

```
Running "wiredep" task

Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task
Verifying property wiredep.target exists in config...OK
Files: grunt-test.html, application/views/inc/inc_scripts.php, application/views
/inc/inc_head.php
Verifying property wiredep.target.src exists in config...OK
Options: src=["grunt-test.html","application/views/inc/inc_scripts.php","application/views/inc/inc_head.php"], directory="assets/bower_components", bowerJson="a ssets/bower.json",fileTypes={"php":{"block":{},"detect":{"js":{},"css":{}},"replace":{"js":"<script src=\"{{filePath}}\"></script>","css":"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"{{filePath}}\" />"}},"html":{"block":{},"detect":{"js":{},"css":{}},"replace":{"js":"<script src=\"{{filePath}}\"></script>","css":"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"{{filePath}}\" />"}}}

Done, without errors.
```

But nothing happens. I've made sure that I'm using the right tags and even tried adding an HTML file (grunt-test.html) to make sure it's not a filetype thing, but I'm at a loss right now.

What do you guys see?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it's matching the src files, so it must not be matching the bower comments in the src files (assuming nothing has changed with the bower components). Maybe it would help if you shared one of the php files for reference?

Comment: In the end, the problem was related to the fact that bower_components wasn't in the same folder as the gruntfile.js. When I put both in the same folder, it worked.